# Subsequences of a basic sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose ($x_n$) is a basic sequence in a Banach space $X$, and $Y$ is a closed, infinite co-dimensional subspace of the closed span of $(x_n)$. Can we always find a subsequence ($y_n$) of ($x_n$) such that the intersection between $Y$ and the closed span of $(y_n)$ is trivial? I think the answer is 'yes' if $Y$ is finite dimensional, but I am not sure otherwise.

Edit: Indeed, it was a typo. Thanks for the bounty.

Comment: That's an interesting question. Definitely true for finite dimensional $Y$.

Comment: I don't see what prevents $(x_n)$ from being contained in $Y$ (when $Y$ is infinite-dimensional), which obviously makes finding such $(y_n)$  impossible. @Theo

Comment: Oh, it says basic sequence, not basis, I read it wrong. I think the question is nontrivial if $(x_n)$ is a basis, or if $Y$ is infinite codimensional in the closed span of $(x_n)$. @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof